# Can a symmetric rank-1 symmetric tensor be written as a linear combination of other symmetric rank-1 symmetric tensors?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, tensor-rank

I know that a symmetric tensor of symmetric rank $1$ can be viewed as a point on the so-called *Veronese variety*. A symmetric tensor of rank $r$ is then in the linear space spanned by $r$ points of the Veronese variety. My question is the following: can any given symmetric tensor of **rank $1$** ever reside in the linear space spanned by $r$ *other* points of the Veronese *variety*, *i.e.* be written as a linear combination of $r$ *other* symmetric rank-$1$ symmetric tensors?

I am an engineer, currently working on tensor decompositions for signal processing applications. I'm not very familiar with algebraic geometry, but it seems that I need the answer to the question above, to ensure uniqueness of one such decomposition. I looked for (a hint toward) an answer in the literature on Veronese varieties, but it is rather hard to dig into.

Comment: Your post contains things I have no familiarity with so I'm not sure if you're over-complicating a really simple question or asking a higher level question. A rank 1 tensor on a vector space is always (trivially) symmetric. It certainly can reside in the span of $r$ other tensors: the tensor $dx+dy$ is in the span of $\{dx,dy\}$.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but a rank-$1$ tensor is not always symmetric: $X = a \circ b \circ c$ i a $3$-rd order rank-$1$ tensor, but it isn't a *symmetric* tensor. The question is then: if $dx$ and $dy$ *are symmetric* and symmetric rank $1$, can $\alpha dx + \beta dy$ ever be symmetric rank-$1$ again?

Comment: Ah ok you're referring to the decomposability rank. What definitions are you using of "symmetric" and "symmetric rank 1"? For concreteness maybe give me an example in $\mathbb{R}^2\otimes\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Also are these real or complex vector spaces? Or both?

Comment: I'm sorry; what you take as the rank in your first answer is what I know as the *order*. My definitions can be found in http://www.gipsa-lab.grenoble-inp.fr/~pierre.comon/FichiersPdf/ComoGLM08-simax.pdf. And we're looking at $\mathbb{C}$. Thanks in advance for looking into this!

Comment: Ok after thinking about this for a bit I'm starting to see why it's a n on-trivial question (lol). For $\mathbb{R}$ vector spaces the answer is easily no, but it follows from the fact that the square of a scalar is positive. Obviously this doesn't work for $\mathbb{C}$, in which case you end up with some polynomials, solutions to which could be non-trivial linear combinations that equal your tensor. But you're probably aware of most of this.

Comment: You could try reposting this with a different title with an explanation of your original problem (regarding tensors), followed by an explanation of why it leads you to investigate solutions of polynomials. I say this because, for example, people who might be able to answer your question might not know what the Veronese variety is (maybe it's not intrinsic to your problem and there's a really simple solution that doesn't require AG), and OTOH people who know what it is might not know why it's related to your question about tensors (maybe the Veronese variety arises independently in AG).

Comment: So both classes of people might have seen this question and skipped it. Maybe that's why you didn't get any answers. Also, the "rank" of a tensor to me is what you call the order, so you may want to call it "decomposability rank". Better yet, since you're interested in decomposability rank-$1$ tensors, you can just call them "pure tensors" (more people will recognize this language I think).

Comment: Also, a symmetric tensor is as I understand it just a rank-$1$ tensor that happens to be symmetric, so the language in your title is redundant. I think a clearer title would be "When can a symmetric pure tensor be written as a sum of other symmetric pure tensors?" And finally if you don't get any responses for a few days, you can try Mathoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is: Can a given symmetric tensor of rank $1$ be written as a linear combination of other symmetric tensors of rank $1$? The answer is yes. Yes, a symmetric tensor of rank $1$ can be written as a linear combination of other symmetric tensors of rank $1$. This is true over the complex numbers, the real numbers, and other fields. For simplicity I'll write this answer over a field of characteristic zero; everything I say will be valid over real numbers and over complex numbers. (It can also be valid over other fields with mild conditions but I will ignore that for now.)

Before proceeding with generalities, perhaps a concrete example might be helpful? Let $V$ be a two-dimensional vector space with basis $x,y$. (You are welcome to think of this as $V = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $x = (1,0)$, $y=(0,1)$.) One of the symmetric tensors of rank $1$, and order $3$, in $V \otimes V \otimes V$, is $x \otimes x \otimes x$, which for short we might denote $x^3$. Can we write this $x^3$ as a linear combination of other rank $1$ symmetric tensors? Yes, in various ways; here is one.
$$
\begin{split}
  (x+y) \otimes (x+y) \otimes (x+y) &= x \otimes x \otimes x + x \otimes x \otimes y \\
  &\quad + x \otimes y \otimes x + y \otimes x \otimes x \\
  &\quad + x \otimes y \otimes y + y \otimes x \otimes y \\
  &\quad + y \otimes y \otimes x + y \otimes y \otimes y \\
  &= x^3 + 3x^2y + 3xy^2 + y^3,
\end{split}
$$
where $x^3 = x \otimes x \otimes x$, $x^2y = \frac{1}{3}(x \otimes x \otimes y + x \otimes y \otimes x + y \otimes x \otimes x)$, and in general $xyz = \frac{1}{6}(x \otimes y \otimes z + \text{all permutations})$.

Well,
$$
  (x+y)^3 + (x-y)^3 = x^3 + 6xy^2,
$$
and
$$
  (x+2y)^3 + (x-2y)^3 = x^3 + 24xy^2 .
$$
So therefore
$$
  4(x+y)^3 + 4(x-y)^3 - (x+2y)^3 - (x-2y)^3 = 3x^3.
$$
So the rank $1$ symmetric tensor $x^3$ is in the span of the $4$ rank $1$ symmetric tensors $(x \pm y)^3$ and $(x \pm 2y)^3$.

Now, this example begins to point the way to a more general answer. Because when we consider the space of symmetric tensors in $V \otimes V \otimes V$—it is a subspace that can be denoted $S^3 V$ ($S$ for Symmetric), or $S_3 V$, depending on the author—we see that it has dimension $4$. A basis is given by $x^3, x^2y, xy^2, y^3$. And another different basis is given by $(x\pm y)^3$, $(x \pm 2y)^3$. At that point it becomes clear that *every* symmetric tensor is a linear combination of those $4$ symmetric rank $1$ tensors, *including* all the symmetric rank $1$ tensors such as $x^3$.

So we have the first answer to your question: Let $V$ be any finite dimensional vector space. Let $d \geq 1$. Let $N$ be the dimension of $S^d V$. Now $S^d V$ is spanned by the symmetric rank $1$ tensors, so we can take some $N$ of them to form a basis. And now all the symmetric rank $1$ tensors can be written as linear combinations of those.

Now there is a reasonable follow-up question, which might perhaps be a natural question from a standpoint of an engineer who is interested in identifiability issues: Okay, if some symmetric rank $1$ tensor is equal to a linear combination of some $r$ other symmetric rank $1$ tensors, then what is $r$?

We can certainly have such linear combinations when $r=N$ (the dimension of $S^d V$) but unfortunately it can happen sooner than that. It happens as soon as $r=d+1$. Because if $V$ has a basis $x_1,\dotsc,x_n$, then $x_1^d$ can be written as a linear combination of $(x_1 + t_i x_2)^d$ for any (!) $d+1$ nonzero values of $t_i$. (Nutshell: with Vandermonde matrices you can show these are linearly independent, and there are enough of them to span all the degree $d$ polynomials in $x_1,x_2$, including $x_1^d$.)

I believe the converse may be true: if $L^d$ is a linear combination of some $r$ other symmetric rank $1$ tensors, then $r \geq d+1$. But at the moment I'm not sure where to find a result along those lines. (I looked in some papers of Reznick and the book of Iarrobino-Kanev; it might be in there somewhere but so far I have not been able to find it.) If you are interested, please let me know and I will be happy to resume the search.

Answer (score 0):

First let me make a point about the terminology. I believe what you mean by "rank-$1$ tensor" is what most people call a "pure" tensor: it is a tensor $t$ that can be written $v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_n$ for some possibly different vectors $v_i$. I believe what you mean by "pure symmetric" is that all the $v_i$ are the same; you can prove that this is equivalent to being pure and symmetric separately, so the language "symmetric pure symmetric" is redundant.

Let $t=v\otimes\cdots\otimes v$ be a pure symmetric tensor. Choose a basis $E_i$ in which $v=E_1$, and suppose $v$ can be written as a linear combination of pure tensors. Then

$$E_1\otimes\dots\otimes E_1 = v\otimes\dots\otimes v = \sum_k w^k_1\otimes...\otimes w_1^k$$

for some vectors $w_k=\sum_i c_k^i E_i$. Thus

$$E_1\otimes\dots\otimes E_1=\sum_{k,J}c_k^{i_1}\cdots c_k^{i_j}E_{i_1}\otimes\cdots\otimes E_{i_j}$$

A basis representation of a vector is unique, so equating the coefficients on both sides, we see that the coefficient of each $E_{i_1}\otimes\cdots\otimes E_{i_k}$ on the right is a polynomial in the $c_i^k$ that must be equal to $0$ or, in the case $i_1=\cdots=i_j=1$, equal to $1$; the solution is obtained by checking the common solutions of these equations. In particular for $n\ne 1$,

$$\sum_k c_k^n\cdots c_k^n = 0$$

If your vector space is even dimensional and real, then each term in this sum is an even power of a real number, thus  positive, and thus each term must be zero. In other words, $c_k^n=0$ for $n\ne 1$. This means each $w_i$ is a scalar multiple of $E_1$, so the answer to your question is no.

For odd dimensional real vector spaces and complex vector spaces it seems like the solution would be more complicated.